# Multibinding Converter ConvertBack not called

Tags: c#, wpf

Ive created a `multibinding` like this

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="5" Name="UtskicksadressTextBoxOnTjanstFlik">
<TextBox.Text>
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConvertUtskickadress}" Mode="TwoWay">
<Binding Path="TjanstDataContainerNavigator.DataContainer.Current.intUtskickadress" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
<Binding Path="TjanstDataContainerNavigator.DataContainer.Current.bolAnlAdrSomUtskicksAdr"></Binding>
</MultiBinding>
</TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Im setting the value for

```
<Binding Path="TjanstDataContainerNavigator.DataContainer.Current.intUtskickadress" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
```

in my `viewmodel` manually.

I expect `ConvertBack` to run when i do this. But nothing. `ConvertBack` method runs as expected when i change the value from my view. So my converter binding seems to be correct

Comment: ConvertBack method will be called only if `Text` changed of your TextBox.

Comment: If target property changes `ConvertBack` gets called and if source property changes `Convert` method gets called.

Comment: yup i simply misunderstood how converters work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `target property` changes `ConvertBack` gets called and if `source property` changes `Convert` method gets called.

So whenever Text is changed from view, ConvertBack method gets called and whenever any binding property changes Convert method will be called.